# How to efficiently make a numbered list in python Class-list

Tags: python, processing-efficiency, coding-efficiency

How to make the following code more compact and efficient.

Here, the code was to find the position where certain numerical value resides in the list.
For example, given set of number

```
ListNo = [[100,2,5], [50,10], 4, 1, [6,6,500]]
```

The value of 100, 50 and 500 was in the position of 0,3 and 9, respectively.

The testing code was as follows

```
ListNo = [[100,2,5], [50,10], 4, 1, [6,6,500]]
NumberedList = ListNo
Const = 0
items = 0

for i, item in enumerate(ListNo):
    MaxRange = len(item) if isinstance(item, list) else 1

    for x in range(0, MaxRange):
        if MaxRange > 1:
            NumberedList[i][x] = Const
        else:
            NumberedList[i] = Const
        Const = Const + 1

print(NumberedList)
```

> > [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4], 5, 6, [7, 8, 9]]

My question is, whether there is another option to make this code more compact and efficient.

Comment: Fails for `ListNo = [1, [2], 3]`

Comment: I dont get you, I can run the code w/o problem at my side

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Find the index of a certain item in a list?

Comment: @RodneyPetrusbalandong: It outputs `[0, 1, 2]`, but should output `[0, [1], 2]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.count`:

```
from itertools import count
i = count()
print([[next(i) for _ in range(len(l))] if isinstance(l, list) else next(i) for l in ListNo])
```

This outputs:

```
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4], 5, 6, [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Thanks, that look more elegant

Comment: Just curious, why the need of, i = count(), instead of i=0?

Comment: This is to make use of the iterator that `itertools.count()` returns, so that when `next(i)` is called, the next number in the sequence is returned. Please refer to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) of `itertools.count()` for details.

Answer (score 2):

A recursive solution would be more elegant, and handle more cases:

```
def nested_list_ordinal_recurse(l, it):
    if isinstance(l, list):
        return [nested_list_ordinal_recurse(item, it) for item in l]
    else:
        return next(it)

def nested_list_ordinal(l, _it=None):
    return nested_list_ordinal_recurse(l, itertools.count())
```

Comment: haha just arrived at the same solution. Yours is a bit more readable. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

```
ListNo = [[100,2,5], [50,10], 4, 1, [6,6,500]];
count=-1
def counter(l=[]):
     global count
     if l:
      return [counter() for i in l]
     else:
         count+=1
         return count
print [counter(item) if isinstance(item, list) else counter()  for item in ListNo ]
```

Without iter tools